# Rails scope where clause appears to be cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Using Rails 3.2.22.5, Ruby 2.0.0-p648, I have this query, which among other things is supposed to return patients less than 18 years old:

```
scope :should_be_underage, joins("left join patient_status on patient_status.patient_id = patient.patient_id left join patient_state on patient_state.patient_id = patient.patient_id LEFT JOIN patient_account ON patient_account.patient_id = patient.patient_id INNER JOIN account_covers_disease ON account_covers_disease.account_id = patient_account.account_id").where("patient.dob > ?", 18.years.ago).where("((patient_state.patient_particip_status_id <> 7 and patient_account.patient_account_status = 1 and account_covers_disease.disease_id = 2) OR ((patient_status.patient_status_id not in (9, 36)) and patient_account.patient_account_status = 1 and account_covers_disease.disease_id = 1))").uniq
```

This runs fine, but a few days ago it seemed like the results of where("patient.dob > ?", 18.years.ago) had been cached.  We were getting patients returned who were four days past their 18th birthday.  When I artificially set one of those patient's birthdays back a day, they fell out of the results.  When I returned the patient to the original birthday, they joined the results again.  So it seems that the query as a whole was not being cached.

Five days later, I tried again, and now the query was returning patients nine days past their 18th birthday, i.e., the same group of patients.  I tried the artificial birthday reset test again and again it worked.  It's as if just the value of 18.years.ago had been cached, but the query otherwise runs dynamically.

When I rebuilt the codebase, the problem went away, but that's obviously not a production solution.  Does anyone know what's going on here and how I can correct it?  Thanks.

Comment: Could the problem be the system clock on the production machine?

Comment: Or, do you have something in a controller/view that's performing some dodgy caching, e.g. on `Patient.max(:id)`? (When you say "re-running the query, are you doing this directly in the console, or via a web request?)

Comment: When you say "rebuilt the codebase and it worked", *what changed*? If this happens again, you can try performing the "rebuilding" process one step at a time, to see what fixes it... Does your "rebuild" refresh the rails cache? The database cache? Does it delete any temporary files? Does it restart the server? Did you restart the whole VM? Did you re-seed the database? ....... Try to track down *which step* fixes it.

Comment: This is in a web application served by Nginx and Passenger.  Instead of "rebuilt the codebase", I should have more clearly said that I restarted the application by touching the tmp/restart.txt file and reloading the site.

Comment: I should have also mentioned that I have a staging site on the same server that is not having this problem.  The codebase differs only slightly, and seemingly irrelevantly, from production.  I can't find any significant differences in the config/environment files either.  The areas involving caching look like this:

Comment: (Must learn that hitting enter twice adds the comment).

Comment: Production -   config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
Staging -   config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
Not sure that the problem is anywhere here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could/should put the relation expression in a lambda so the date is evaluated when called, not just at load time

```
scope :should_be_underage, -> { joins(...).where(...) }
```

Alternatively you could put the expression in a static method

```
def self.should_be_underage
  joins(...)
    .where(...)
    .uniq
end
```

Fire up the console and check what query is being used

```
> Patient.should_be_underage.to_sql
```

Call `to_sql` twice here to see how/if the query changes. I imagine at the moment it is unchanging but with a lambda it will re-evaluate each call.

Comment: This was it.  It wasn't caching, but my original syntax was causing "18.years.ago" to be evaluated only upon restarting of the application.  (It seemed like my staging environment didn't have the problem only because I restart staging more frequently).  When I changed to the lambda syntax, the date evaluated each time.  Thanks to Tom and Josh for their comments also.  This is my first time posting to Stack Overflow and the responses were extremely prompt and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If caching is indeed breaking your results, you can verify this by wrapping your query in a block like so:

```
Model.uncached do 
  # ... 
end
```